# $\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\tan(x)}{|x|}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\tan(x)}{|x|}$$

Graphing the function $f(x)=\frac{\tan(x)}{|x|}$ using [Desmos](http://desmos.com/) shows that as we approach $x=-1$, the $y$-value gets closer to $-1.557$.

So, we can say that the limit is equal to $-1.557$.

But doing that algebraically is not that simple.

When substituting $x=-1$ in the function we get: $\frac{tan(-1)}{|-1|}$.

If we consider $-1=-\pi$, we get :

$0/\pi$ = $0$, which is not the value that we saw in the graph.

So, the question is: should we consider $-1$ as $-\pi$ ? If not, how to deal with $\tan(-1)$?

Comment: *"if we consider (-1) to be $-\pi$"* -- Why? Just plugging in $-1$ in the expression gives you the desired result which is $\tan(-1)\approx-1.557$ since $\frac{\tan x}{|x|}$ is defined at $x=-1$, why would you consider it to be something else?

Comment: If the problem really is as quoted, $\tan x$ is continuous at $x=1$, so the limit is $\tan(-1)$.

Comment: $\tan(-1) = \frac{\sin(-1)}{\cos(-1)} = - \frac{\sin(1)}{\cos(1)}$. $1$ is a perfectly valid argument for both the sine and the cosine so I don't see your problem.

Comment: @hakim but how to get $tan(-1)$ without using a calculator ?

Comment: You can't evaluate $\tan(-1)$ without calculator. You just leave the limit in his exact form, or you approximate it using a calculator.

Comment: Yes, check out my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to-1}\frac{\tan x}{|x|}=\frac{\tan(-1)}{|-1|}=\tan(-1)=-\tan(1)$$

Since $\tan(-1)$ doesn't have a nice solution, you just leave the limit in his exact form, or you approximate it using a calculator ($\tan(-1)\approx-1.56$).

Comment: very clear. Thanks

Comment: I'd rewrite it as $-\tan(1)$, but that's not necessary.